# get objects from list and return in right form

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Sorry for my English. I need Json in the format, e.g:

```
Contact
{
    “name1”: integer,
    “name”: string
}
```

I'm using Spring boot and adding the following lines

```
System.setProperty("spring.jackson.serialization.INDENT_OUTPUT", "true");
System.setProperty("spring.jackson.serialization.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE", "true");

@JsonRootName(value = "lot")
public class Contact {
```

but, I'm sending data from the controller in List, and now i have next format:

```
{
  "List" : [ {
    "id" : 3,
    "name" : "Baaaaa"
  }, {
    "id" : 4,
    "name" : "Baaaaa"
  },
```

How i can get that i need? Please help me

I need that

```
Contact
    {
        “name1”: integer,
        “name”: string
    }
```

Comment: The first `text` is not JSON

Comment: in my task write that nedd one of to two ways: contacts: [ Contact, ... ]

Contact
{
 “id”: integer,
  “name”: string
}

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send and receive a JSON object from/to your view you can do it easily with Jackson2, i can't understand why you need to get that format this looks like that you are trying to generate a new json model every time.

Please upload more of your code to understand a little bit more,
Regards.

Comment: in my task i need one of two form of json: contacts: [ Contact, ... ] or Contact { “id”: integer, “name”: string }. And I have list of contacts, that's all that i have

Comment: i can't understand you, what is your native language?

Comment: I'm not asking about your programming language, what language do you speak?

Comment: Ukrainian my native language)

Comment: Ok, can you edit the article and post more of your code because is complicated to understand with this few information.

Comment: Насколько я понял ты и по русски поймешь?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with using ObjectMapper. For more information about it ,you can look this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_objectmapper.htm)